# JPA by kotlin: by lazy and @Transient not work with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, kotlin, spring-data

I use kotlin with JPA in my project but the kotlin's by lazy delegation seems not work with hibernate:

```
    @get:Transient
    private val shop:Shop by lazy { shopService.shop(shopId!!) }
```

and I get error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: kotlin.Lazy, at table: order, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(shop$delegate)]
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:456) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:423) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:597) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:461) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
... 20 common frames omitted
```

Is something I missing here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The delegates are stored as a *field* in your class. As such it'll be accessed `shop$delegate`.

You might need to mark the delegate as transient as well:

```
@delegate:Transient
@get:Transient
private val shop:Shop by lazy { shopService.shop(shopId!!) }
```

Comment: Helped me, Thanks! Annotation on getter is not required and could be removed.

Comment: I get a NullPointerException when I try this. Looks like when Hibernate deserializes the entity out of the database the transient field initialisers don't fire, so shop is null.

Comment: @RobertElliot it sounds like you're not using a delegate here.